# Replacing strings using regex

Tags: .net, regex, c#-4.0

I have a very simple regex that seems to work in in online regex testing systems but when I plug it into my code it fails.

I would like to remove items between two comments in html.

I am using the following code to do so:

```
string source = x;
String matchpattern = @"<!-- link -->.*<!-- /link -->";
String replacementpattern = @"";
string result = Regex.Replace(source, matchpattern, replacementpattern);
```

where x is the following:

```
<!-- link -->\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<p class=\"backToTop\"><a href=\"#content\">    Back to top</a></p>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<!-- /link -->
```

If anyone has any ideas then they would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\n` in `x` is confusing it... but it's easy to fix. Just add a fourth argument of [`RegexOptions.Singleline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) so that `.` still matches `\n`.

to your `Replace` call:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(source, matchPattern, replacementPattern,
                              RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Comment: @Prib: Just be aware that things will go bad if `x` contains more than one pair of comments (because the regex will match from the first `<!-- link -->` to the last `<!-- /link -->`). Using `.*?` instead of `.*` makes this a little safer.

Answer (score 0):

Set single line option `(?s)`, e.g.: `(?s)<!-- link -->.*<!-- /link -->`